# Media queries problems

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I used everything already and I have no idea, why my @Media Queries doesnt work. "viewport" is already added to HTML head, `@media` are in the end of CSS document.

CSS code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .bio_img {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .bio_photo {
    width: 30%;
  }

  .youtube {
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your HTML too. And please respond soon, else your question will be closed as unclear.

Comment: it works good, can I ask you where you put `media queries` in you css file? and do you have another query?

Comment: We cannot help you without your HTML, or even more of your CSS as we do not know what rules apply and where, so we do not know the result you are seeing, which is an issue. The query you posted looks like it should work, so _something else_ must be happening.

Comment: hi, I put media queries in the end of css file.I tried also to put it as external document and connect it with html but still doesnt work. I use Brackets to write and have preview.

Comment: please share your HTML code too...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adka_d/e68of5sL/ - there is my code (sorry, I am still green in webdev)

and there is my page which I try to make responsive: www.adriannadziadyk.co.nf

Comment: no one could fix my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the // comments.

CSS cant read that. you need /* comment goes here */

in this case you should use

```
/* Tablet diagonal width:768px */
```

here is a link with your code and the test.

https://jsfiddle.net/Willox_san/e68of5sL/2/

good luck!

Comment: I also ordered them but thats not essential.